# Does SDWebImage Framework Automaticcaly use Grand Central Dispatch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch, sdwebimage

Say if I have the block of code below;

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

...

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Here we use the new provided sd_setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
    [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"My Text";
    return cell;
}
```

Do I need to worry about enclosing any of it in Grand Central Dispatch blocks, or is all that already handled for us?

Comment: No, you don't need to worry about it, SDWebImage Handles it all for us.

Comment: Exactly, and apart from that, it's an open source project, so you can read its code (and learn from it).

Comment: Please don't learn from it